# JUnit Test error

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to run a JUnit test for my program, however I am getting error message like

```
*incompatible types
required: int[];
found: int *
```

Here is the code that shows the error

```
myQSArray = QS.quickSort(sortedArray2,0, sortedArray2.length - 1);
```

and here is my call for **quickSort method**

```
public static int quickSort( int A[], int p, int r){
    int q; 
    if (p<r)
    {
         q = partition(A,p,r);
         quickSort(A, p, q-1);
         quickSort(A,q+1,r);
    }
    return QS1.quickSort(A, p, r);
}
```

Help Please, thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the method signature for the `partition` method - and the declaration of `sortedArray2` from the method call where the error occurs - plus the declaration of `msQSArray` (THAT should be `int`)

Comment: And please double check the class name, is it `QS` or `QS1` or are you really using to different classes that implement static `quicksort` methods.

Comment: @Andreas_D:  public static int partition(int A[],int p, int r){

Comment: @Andreas_D: Here are the Declaration for sortedArray2 and msQSArray

Comment: int[] sortedArray1 = new int[SIZE];
  int[] sortedArray2 = new int[SIZE];
  int[] myQSArray = new int[SIZE];

Comment: Unlike you said the myQSArray is of type int[] rather than int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems with your code:

The method is declared to return an `int` value but you try to assign this `int` to an `int[]`. That causes the actual compiletime error. Change the method signature to

```
public static int[] quickSort( int A[], int p, int r)
```

for a quick fix.

**Then**, your recursive function `quicksort` misses the exit criteria. It will run indefinitely (or at least until the virtual machine gives up and throws a `StackOverflowException` after a couple of milliseconds). You *need* to add a criteria to check, if the array is sorted and return the sorted array (see the "new" method signature!).

Comment: Thank you @Andreas, that definitely helped. Now when I run the JUnit Test, I got 0% pass, so basically, everything failed, so is that because of the "exit criteria", and what is this "new" method signature again?

Comment: ah sorry, the "new" part of the signature is that the method returns `int[]` now instead of `int`. We want to get the sorted array rather then some single integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Java Error incompatible types occurred when a compiler found a variable and expression whose data type is not compatible to perform an operation on them.And this is the one of the way.

**better once refer you declared the "sortedArray2" as int[] array type or not**

Comment: Sorry @mohan, but I didn't get what you mean. Do you want me to check the "sortedArray2" declaring statement or is that a suggestion? Please clearify.